# Not Applicable for the Arguments

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a progress message when a preference is selected:

```
        Preference prefLocation = (Preference) findPreference("location");
    prefLocation.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Location" , "Finding location...", true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

However I'm getting an error in Eclipse:

```
The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}, String, String, boolean)
```

However, when I execute the line before the setOnPreferenceClickListener, it compiles fine!

I'm probably revealing my severe inexperience in Java, but would appreate a clue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in that case you are passing a reference to the inneer activity (an `OnPreferenceClickListener`) instead of a context (which usually must be your activity). Change it to this and it will work:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, "Location" , "Finding location...", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to read, really read carefully, the error message the compiler is emitting.

The compiler is complaining about this line:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Location" , "Finding location...", true);
```

the `ProgressDialog.show()` method requires a `Context` as the first parameter.

You passed `this` from within the `OnPreferenceClickListener` class, so you're passing an `OnPreferenceClickListener` instead of a `Context`.

Comment: Yes, sorry it makes 100% sense now, I knew the "this" everywhere was going to byte me some or other time!

Answer (score 1):

`this` in this context is the `OnPreferenceClickListener`, not the outer class.

If you want to refer that, you'll have to do

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourClassName.this, "Location" , "Finding location...", true);
```

`YourClassName` being the class of your preference activity (or whatever you're in).

Comment: Thanks EboMike, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on my Async Task.this is works like charm.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityAddTicket.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.processing);
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            dialog.show();
        };
```